# Scheme vs Common Lisp

Tags: scheme, common-lisp

Scheme vs Common-Lisp ?
What to choose ?

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: To learn functional programming but then I find out that there is some dialects to Lisp, so I don't know which one . I accept any suggestion.

Comment: I would recommend that you read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108201/common-lisp-or-scheme

Comment: From your question it seems that you have to start and choose one, my suggestion is to pick the one you have more valuable information for, is it a nice book, a colleague or a friend. Learn one and later on choose, with a solid background on your shoulders, it will not be wasted time.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108201/common-lisp-or-scheme

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Scheme is small and clean, Common Lisp is big and powerful.

Comment: PLT Scheme (now called Racket) is clean, well documented, and comes with a slick IDE. It's also pre-packaged. Common Lisp would take a while to get up and running. If you're just starting out, I'd start with Scheme.

Comment: I think that's history. R6RS is no longer clean and small. Actual Scheme software never was more clean than the corresponding Lisp software.

Comment: @Rainer Joswig "relatively small"?

Comment: @pst, checkout R6RS. It is dense and several hundred pages with really complex stuff.

Comment: Um, used to be relatively small and clean, back when I did anything with it?  (And, yes, small and clean languages don't necessarily produce clean code.)

Answer (score 5):

For the aim of learning functional languages, as indicated by one of your comments, Scheme has the advantage of being the subject of [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), which was a near ubiquitous standard undergraduate text up into the early 2000s, designed to ease people with no experience into the world of programming. It's not the easiest book to just pick up and read (which is probably why it has been slowly displaced), but if you can get into it then there are quite a few road to Damascus-style moments. Even as someone who read that book at university but now works with mostly procedural languages, going back and reading it again recently gave me a few zen moments.

Printed copies are still standard computer science textbook prices, but the full text is available from the website above. So it's at least worth checking out.

Answer (score 4):

Another option to consider is [Clojure](http://clojure.org/). It is another "lisp dialect" and has a good bit in common with CL -- with some twists. Advantages of using it are JVM/Java interaction as well as the native concurrency which includes STM.

Although, if I was "just learning" I'd choose Scheme and have a field-day with continuations/call-cc :-) It's definitely one of the more "academic" lisp dialects. On the other hand, the pure insanity ... err, power ... of [non-hygienic macros](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2002/09/13/hygienic-macros) make for some interesting macros in CL.